# while using wikipedia module in a python project shows this error

Tags: python

MY CODE:

```
import wikipedia
from wikipedia import *



search=wikipedia.search("apple")

print(search)
```

ERROR:

```
File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\demoprojects\web scraping\wikipedia.py", line 2, in <module>
    import wikipedia
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\demoprojects\web scraping\wikipedia.py", line 7, in <module>
    search=wikipedia.search("apple")
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'wikipedia' has no attribute 'search' (most likely due to a circular import)

when i used pip install wikipedia it shows this:
Requirement already satisfied: wikipedia in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from wikipedia) (4.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from wikipedia) (2.26.0)    
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia) (2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->wikipedia) (2.2.1)
```

Comment: You have named your file ```wikipedia.py```. You are importing your own file instead of ```wikipedia``` module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\demoprojects\web scraping\wikipedia.py"
```

You have a file named `wikipedia.py`. When you do `import wikipedia`, you are basically importing your own file instead of `wikipedia` module. So rename you file to something else.